# How do I time my npm install?

Tags: node.js, performance, npm, dependency-management, profiler

I am trying to see how much time `npm install` takes to complete installing all my dependencies. Is there a way for me to time this process, natively (in npm) or using some third party plugin? I've tried 
 * `npm i --verbose`
 * `npm i --silly`
 * `slow-deps` (A third party lib that analyzes your npm packages)

`slow-deps` gave me a decent result, but I am not sure about it's accuracy, as it doesn't run as part of the `npm install` process.

Is there any other way to **accurately** time-profile the `npm install` process? I'm looking for an output like this (output screenshot from Yarn):

[image]

Comment: `time npm install`?

Comment: Could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your help. I have come across a few utilities for this:

- The `time` utility mentioned by @JJJ in the comments section.
- Paypal's `gnomon` package, that updates timestamps to everything.

Comment: Didn't know [gnomon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gnomon), instantly to my tools-belt :-)

Comment: npm 9.2.0 outputs on stderr (strange to me...), so to use gnomon with it you need to do `npm install --verbose 2>&1 | gnomon`. Unluckily, gnomon project is archived, unmaintained, and without updated forks... :-/

Answer (score 1):

Use `time` linux command and have the following command:

```
time npm install
```

Also according to https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/time.1.html

> Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.

so your command may be (I am a macOS user and I am using the below command):

```
/usr/bin/time npm install
```

The output of this command (at the last line) would be something like this:

```
153.96 real        67.63 user        34.12 sys
```

so basically what you are looking at is the `real` number that are in seconds. To the above example the time taken is:

```
153.96s
```